# LibGDX nested table display and input

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to make a wordsearch app using libgdx.
Created a AbstractScreen class which implements Screen
I extend this AbstractScreen class to create different screens for the game.

AbstractScreen.java

```
public abstract class AbstractScreen implements Screen
{
// the fixed viewport dimensions (ratio: 1.6)
public static final int GAME_VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 1080, GAME_VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 1920;
public static final int MENU_VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 1080, MENU_VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 1920;

protected final WordSearch1 game;
protected final Stage stage;

private BitmapFont font;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Skin skin;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private Table table;

public AbstractScreen(WordSearch1 game )
{
    this.game = game;
    int width = ( isGameScreen() ? GAME_VIEWPORT_WIDTH : MENU_VIEWPORT_WIDTH );
    int height = ( isGameScreen() ? GAME_VIEWPORT_HEIGHT : MENU_VIEWPORT_HEIGHT );

    this.stage = new Stage();
}

//**** Removed some method for this post ****

protected Table getTable()
{
    if( table == null ) {
        table = new Table( getSkin() );
        table.setFillParent( true );
        if( WordSearch1.DEV_MODE ) {
            table.debug();
        }
        stage.addActor( table );
    }
    return table;
}

// Screen implementation

@Override
public void show()
{
    Gdx.app.log( WordSearch1.LOG, "Showing screen: " + getName() );

    // set the stage as the input processor
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( stage );
}

@Override
public void resize(
    int width,
    int height )
{   
    Gdx.app.log( WordSearch1.LOG, "Resizing screen: " + getName() + " to: " + width + " x " + height );
}

@Override
public void render(
    float delta )
{
    stage.act( delta );

    // clear the screen with the given RGB color (black)
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f );
    Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // draw the actors
    stage.draw();

    // draw the table debug lines
    Table.drawDebug( stage );
}
}
```

GameScreen.java

```
public class GameScreen extends AbstractScreen
{
public GameScreen( WordSearch1 game )
{
super( game );
}

@Override
public void show()
{
super.show();
TextButton startGameButton = new TextButton( "Start game", getSkin() );


String[][] data = gets a 2D array of letters for grid
// retrieve the default table actor
Table tableR = super.getTable();

Table table = new Table( super.getSkin() );
table.row();

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
TextButton letter = new TextButton( data[i][j], getSkin());
letter.getLabel().setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
Gdx.app.log( WordSearch1.LOG, " -- Grid  Letter: " + letter.getText() );
letter.addListener( new DefaultActorListener() {
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button )
    {   
        //Gdx.app.log( WordSearch1.LOG, " -- Touch  X: " + x + "  Y: " + y );
        //super.touchUp( event, x, y, pointer, button );
        //TextButton b = (TextButton) event.getListenerActor();
        //Gdx.app.log( WordSearch1.LOG, " -- Touch  Name: " + b.getText() );

        //game.getSoundManager().play( TyrianSound.CLICK );
        //game.setScreen( new StartGameScreen( game ) );
    }
} );
table.add( letter ).size( 30, 30 ).spaceBottom( 0 );
    }
table.row();
}

table.row();

table.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
table.addAction(sequence( delay(1.0f), fadeIn( 1.50f )));

//table.debug();

tableR.row();
tableR.add(startGameButton);
tableR.row();
tableR.row();
tableR.add(table); //****Display nicely but input does not work.
tableR.addActor(table); //**** Displays only 1/4th of table
tableR.row();

table.addListener(new InputListener() {

    ArrayList<Integer> hashList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    float scX , scY ; //Start CenterX, CenterY 
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("2- DOWN - Pressed - X : " + x + "  Y: " + y);
        System.out.println("2- DOWN -  HIT : " + stage.hit(x, y, true) );
        hashList.clear();
        float sX = x; //Start X
        float sY = y; //Start Y
        if (stage.hit(sX, sY, true) != null) {
            scX = stage.hit(sX, sY, true).getCenterX();
            scY = stage.hit(sX, sY, true).getCenterY();
            System.out.println("2- DOWN---- DRAG START Center - X : " + scX + "  Y: " + scY);
            System.out.println("2- DOWN---- DRAG START Center - HIT : " + stage.hit(scX, scY, true) );
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("2- UP - Released - X : " + x + "  Y: " + y);
        float upX = x;
        float upY = y;
        float tX = scX; //temp
        float tY = scY; //temp
        String test = "";

        // *** implemented only for Left to Right drag ****

        while (tX <= upX) {
            //System.out.println("2- While : " + test);
            if (stage.hit(tX, tY, true) != null) {
                System.out.println("2- IF : " + test);
                TextButton t = (TextButton) stage.hit(tX, tY, true);
                test = test + t.getText();

            }
            tX = tX + 30;
        }
        System.out.println("2- UP - WORD : " + test);

    }

    // *** implemented only for Left to Right drag ****
    public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {

        //System.out.println("2- Dragged - X : " + x + "  Y: " + y);
        //System.out.println("------- Dragged ------");

        if (stage.hit(x, y, true) != null) {
            int hash = stage.hit(x, y, true).hashCode();

            if (hashList.contains(hash) == false) {
                hashList.add(hash);
                float cX = stage.hit(x, y, true).getCenterX();
                float cY = stage.hit(x, y, true).getCenterY();
                TextButton t = (TextButton) stage.hit(cX, cY, true);
                System.out.println("2- Dragged - hit : " + stage.hit(x, y, true));
                System.out.println("2- Dragged - hit C : " + stage.hit(cX, cY, true));
                System.out.println("2- Dragged - Text : " + t.getText());
            }
            else {
                //System.out.println("2- Dragged - Hash MATCHED : ");
            }


        }
        else {
            System.out.println("2- Dragged - Cancelled : ");
            event.cancel();
        }
     }
});

}
}
```

I have included most of the code above. Now the problem is
 If I use only one table - tableR and get rid of the table then the touchdragged works as expected. Gives me the proper behavior by selecteing letters between start and end points in left-to-right direction.
No I wanted to use tableR as root table and do the rest of UI. So I created a different table - "table" (The above code is when I use both these tables)

Now the problem is

1. If I use tableR.add(table); table with letters is displayed correctly but the input functions does not behave as expected. It hits Label although touchable is disabled for labels of the textbutton.
2. If I use tableR.addActor(table) then the table with letters is not displayed properly. Only the 1/4th -top right part of table is visible and it is aligned to bottom left. Rest of the table is just not visible. Input seems to work perfectly for the 1/4th that is visible.

I can share the full code if that would be helpful.

Please help!!
On a side note please tell me if the inputListener (table.addListener(new InputListener()) is the right way to do it.
My goal is to display a grid of letters and have the touch behavior like in the wordsearch games on market.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the [context](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-help#context) or [problem statement](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-help#problem-statement).

Your example code is too complex. Simplify the problem and post example code that is [executable](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-help#executable-example-code) and can be copied, pasted and run.

`Table` has touchable set to `childrenOnly`. You may want to use `setTouchable(enabled)`. If you only care about touch on the buttons then you don't need to do this (they are also tables but have already done it).

You most likely do not need to call `stage.hit()`. The touch coordinates are given and the event gives lots of information, including the `target`. This is actor that the event originated on, which is probably the button or an actor within the button (eg a Label inside a TextButton). It could be the table if you enable touch on the tables.

Comment: I will upload the project later today.
Thanks

Comment: No project, it should be a single file that can be copy and pasted and run (ie it has a main method).

Comment: I am cleaning up my code. Will upload it in a couple of days.

Comment: Does the following make sense ? Or is it just wrong?

    `stageT.addActor(rootTable);
     rootTable.addActor(gridTable);
     rootTable.setFillParent(true);
     gridTable.setFillParent(true);`

Setting setFillParent(true) for both the tables seem to fix the problem. Will test more and confirm though.

But following post suggests: Only the root table should fill its parent (stage).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483546/libgdx-nesting-tables-for-gameboard-grid

Thanks

Comment: Only the root table should use `setFillParent`.

Comment: Hmmm. Setting setFillParent on both table seems to fix all issues. I am still working on cleaning up code and making it executable from one file. Will post this weekend.